# Is this a known formula? $ \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1 - \frac{a_k}{N}\right)$

Tags: probability, number-theory

I try to quantify a partition, are there any known indicators/caracteristic numbers? Something which came to my mind was
$$ \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1 - \frac{a_k}{N}\right), $$

with the following condition

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = N .$$

Is this a known formula? I'd like to have an indicator which tells me if the partition is well spread or concentrated on some few numbers.
I hope my question is clear as I know not a lot about partitions. Thank you for your help.

Edit: If $a_0=N$ and all others $a_k$ are 0 this formula gives 0. If all $a_k$ are 1 and $n=N$ tends to infinity this formula goes to $\frac{1}{e}$. So I am wondering too if $\frac{1}{e}$ is the upper bound for a finite $N$ for all partitions.

Edit2: Thanks a lot for different proofs that $\frac{1}{e}$ is the upper bound.
I still like to know if someone knows something more about this formula. If someone has an interessing fact, that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$1-x\leq e^{-x},$$ if $x\geq 0,$ the upper bound you state:
$$ \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1 - \frac{a_k}{N}\right)\leq e^{-a_1/N} \times \cdots\times e^{-a_N/N} =e^{-1}, $$ 
holds for any finite partition.

Your measure can be looked at as the $n^{th}$ power of the geometric mean of the relative sizes of the complements of partition atoms.

Comment: thanks for your answer and easy proof! Why is this the $n^{th}$ power of the geometric mean?

Comment: $GM(x_1,..,x_n)=(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)^{1/n}$ so there is a factor missing thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = -\log(1-x)$ for $x \in [0,1)$. 
Since $f''(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} > 0$. $f(x)$ is convex over $[0,1)$.
By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality),
for any $a_0,\ldots, a_n \ge 0$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = N$, we have

$$-\sum_{i=0}^n\log\left(1 - \frac{a_i}{N}\right) \ge -(n+1)\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
In the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}$, all coefficients are positive. This leads to

$$-(n+1)\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^{-k}}{k} >
(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^1 \frac{(n+1)^{-k}}{k} = 1$$
As a result,

$$\prod_{i=0}^n\left(1 - \frac{a_i}{N}\right) \le \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} < e^{-1}$$
In short, $e^{-1}$ is indeed the upper limit for a finite $N$ for all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\bracks{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}}}
\bracks{z^{N}}z^{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}a_{j}}}} =
\bracks{z^{N}}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}}z^{a_{k}}}
\\[1cm]
&\ln\pars{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}}z^{a_{k}}}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}} + a_{k}\ln\pars{z}}
\\[5mm]\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
\bracks{\ln\pars{z} - {1 \over N}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_{k}
\\[1cm] &\
\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}}z^{a_{k}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
z^{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}a_{j}}\expo{-\pars{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}a_{j}}/N} = z^{N}\expo{-1}
\\[1cm]
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\bracks{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{1 - {a_{k} \over N}}}
\bracks{z^{N}}z^{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}a_{j}}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, \bbx{\expo{-1}}
\end{align}